# In using the rule "OG new content notification," (rules_og_new_content) how can I insert the group name in the outgoing email

Tags: 7, rules, organic-groups, tokens

In using the rule OG new content notification (admin/config/workflow/rules/reaction/manage/rules_og_new_content) for a site using [Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og). However, I'd like add in the name (and URL) of the parent group. However, I'm not seeing these options in the tokens ("replacement values").

The Content Type in question has the field `og_group_ref` for which I'm trying to target.

[image]

### What I've tried so far (update):

On a dev instance, as per Pierre's recommendation below, I've added the following 'fetch entity' to the rule.

[image]
[image]

But the email comes in blank, without title on the subject line
[image]

Comment: The best way to accomplish this is to create a [custom token](https://www.drupal.org/node/1308488). In `function myhook_myfunction()` you can query the database and [node_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load/7) the node group you like, otherwise you have, somehow, to pass the node id (nid) through Rules. I hope it helps.

Comment: @mchar The above is more of an answer candidate than a comment. Move it below. I'd be willing to try if you expand it out into an answer. Either way. Comment upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add Action >> Get group members from group audience >> node

Add Loop >> node:og-group-ref

- Add Loop inside loop >> group-members >> rename list_item to list_item2

  - Add Action >> Fetch entity by property >> User >> Mail >> list-item2:mail
  - Add Action >> Fetch entity by property >> OG Memembership >> field_name >> list-item:title >> rename entity_fetched to entity_fetched2
  - Add Action >> Send Mail >> list-item2:mail >> list-item:title

#### End Result:

[image]

(click image to enlarge)

Comment: Definitely an upvote. I've added more to my question. I'm not yet getting the value of the title. Did I miss anything? This approach seems to be the more manageable in the long run. So getting this to work would be great.

Comment: Looks like we made a bit of progress. But from what I can see now near the top of the rules Action screen you added, I wonder why you added the "-0" part in the identifier for your "Fetch entity by id". Can you try without that "-0" to see what result you get? Also, what is that "Send mail" within your loop (is that a "rules component")? And can you also explain a bit the screenprint wiith "subject", etc?

Comment: The offset appears to be a required field. The send mail was in the existing rule (from og_exrtas?). It send s an email to each group member.

Comment: Bounty awarded b/c it's about to expire. Though any additional thoughts are welcomed.

Comment: @rgchi did you try the revised answer?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. This is the configuration I ended up using to get the group name in the email.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

to insert the name of group in the mail, you need to use ***[node:og-group-ref]*** replacement token.

Comment: what if he was referencing multiple OG groups? I am afraid this will print the other groups name as well.

Comment: Yes, it will add both group name, if it will be not an issue then @rgchi can use this token.